# Setting DSO interface for specialized template method

Tags: c++, visual-c++, shared-libraries

I have a class that has a template method:

```
class DoStuffWithAnything {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void doStuff(const T&);
};
```

Note that the method is not defined and will never be defined generically. Compilation units will define the implementation for these methods.

On gcc, I actually have no issue, because if a symbol is not defined it will be searched on the DSO.

On msvc I have a problem, how can I tell MSVC that it should import the definition (and when compiling the DSO, that it should export the definition)?

#### Clarifications

Suppose I have a lib called XX. and the `libXX` has a `class XX`. Also, the `libXX` defines `<> doStuff(const XX&)`.

So, `XX.hpp`

```
class XX {
    //...
};
```

And, `XX.cpp`:

```
#include <XX.hpp>
#include <do_stuff_with_anything.hpp>

//...
template <>
void DoStuffWithAnything::doStuff(const XX&) {
    //...
}
```

So, my `app.exe`, would have a code like that:

```
#include <XX.hpp>
#include <do_stuff_with_anything.hpp>

int main() {
    XX a;
    DoStuffWithAnything stuffer;
    stuffer.doStuff(a);
}
```

`app.exe` must know that `doStuff<XX>` is imported. How can I tell that?

Comment: If I have understand your problem, this should solve it.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/539418/840748

Comment: I clarified the question