# How do I add an external dll to my VS2019 project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have built a dll for libtensorflow, and I now wish to add it to my Visual Studio 2019 C++ project. Can anybody help me do this? If I click **Reference->Add Reference** I cannot find my dll. I want to add an external item as a link, but whenever I do that VS does not give me the option to add as a link. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: If this is native `c++` you should be linking to an import library `.lib` file and not adding references to a dll. If this is .NET / CLR you have tagged the question wrongly.

Comment: Ok. It is C++. How do I link to an import library? I am new to C++, and have more experience with .NET.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. My biggest issue is figuring out how to set up this library so I can use it. I will try something like that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there seems to be a way to do it that involves a workaround including a `.lib` file. There is a similiar question asked that has been answered here:

[Calling functions in a DLL from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539358/calling-functions-in-a-dll-from-c)