# C++ controlling canon camera from EDSDK

Tags: c++, camera, canon-sdk

Hi I'm trying to test control a canon camera via usb in c++ (eventually I want to use it on labview). I'm trying to initialise the camera before I use any other functions, firstly I have the lib and dll files provided with the canon SDK but I don't think I've included them correctly since I get an unresolved external error

```
1>EDSDK.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__EdsInitializeSDK@0 referenced in function _main
```

I'm pretty much new to c++ so I don't have the best idea of what I'm doing, would anyone have any suggestions on how I could get this initialization to work? Also on how to include the lib and dll files correctly? Below is the code I've written.

```
#include "EDSDK.h"
#include "EDSDKErrors.h"
#include "EDSDKTypes.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
EdsError err = EDS_ERR_OK;
EdsCameraRef camera = NULL;
EdsCameraListRef cameraList = NULL;
EdsUInt32 count = 0;
bool isSDKLoaded = false;

// Initialize SDK
err = EdsInitializeSDK(); // If camera is initialised, err = EDS_ERR_OK
if(err == EDS_ERR_OK)
{
isSDKLoaded = true; // isSDKLoaded is true if initialised
printf("SDK initialised");
}

printf("SDK not-initialised\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the linker to link your program with the library. How to tell the linker depends on the tool chain. You should refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had also a long time to figure this out and the following steps worked for me:

In VB, you must link to the folder with the header files and the folder with the lib file. To do so:

In the property page, under C/C++ --> General, add the path to the folder with headers in 'Additional included Directories' (select 'edit' in dropdown list). 
Under Linker --> Input, add in 'Additional Dependencies' the path tot the library folder (select 'edit' in dropdown list).

Put the dll files in C:/Windows folder.

The dll files should be put in the same file as the executable (normally "Debug" folder).

See also : [How do I link a DLL to my project? error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090418/how-do-i-link-a-dll-to-my-project-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol)