# How to call or execute a c++ code from visual studio project in basic?

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Studio project written in Basic. The project creates an API. I also have a C++ code which is compiled using GCC on a Linux system.

The VB project procures data from the user. I want to send that data to the C++ program and execute automatically. How can I achieve this? Can the a.out file, generated when C++ codes are compiled, be of any use?

Regards,

Saurav Agarwal

Visual Studio Version 2010 Ultimate

Comment: You are going to have to recompile your Linux C++ code for Windows. Although I suppose you could use Cygwin or MinGW, but since you have Visual Studio installed, this will be A LOT easier using the Microsoft compiler tools.   In any case, how do you want to accomplish the interop?  With the Basic code as an EXE and the C++ code as a DLL?  Or the other way around?  Or do you want both the Basic and C++ code as seperate executables.  I'm assuming we're talking about VB.net here.

Comment: How can I compile the code for windows?
The C++ code can be either exe or DLL. However, the Basic code is deployed as DLL. Yes, I am working in VB.net

Answer (score 1):

Compile C++ code as a DLL.  VB code uses P/Invoke to get at the function.

From the DLL export one or more "C" functions that is meant to be your API to the VB code:

```
extern "C" void __stdcall Foo(int x, int y)
{
   return;
}
```

Follow the instructions with this answer here for more details on to finish this:

[Exporting functions from a DLL with dllexport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538134/exporting-functions-from-a-dll-with-dllexport)

Comment: How can I compile c++ code as DLL to be imported into VB-net Project?Do I need to rewrite the code again for Visual studio or use the gcc compiler to do so ?