# GoogleTest of static method c++ using header files

Tags: c++, unit-testing, static-methods, googletest

So i need to use gTest.

I have a util class with static functions.

The header file contain the declerations of the functions:

```
class a
{
public:
    a();
    virtual ~a();

    static bool test();
}
```

on the cpp file the implementations:

```
a::a() { }
a::~a() { }
bool a::test() { return true; }
```

on the test unit file i just added a test :

```
TEST(a, a)
{
  EXPECT_EQ(true,a::test());  
}
```

I'm getting a linker error :

```
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl a::test()" (?test@a@@SA_NIPAD0@Z)    UnitTest.obj    UnitTest
```

if the implementation of the static function is in the .h file , everything work smoothly.

is there anyway to uni test static function that way?

Comment: Did you simply miss to link your `.cpp` file to the testrunner?

Comment: How should i do it? usually i'm linking the dll lib.

Comment: @USer22999299 What dll lib are you referring to?

Comment: I have the Unitest project which i references to GoogleTest and to my project that i want to uni test.
In addition to that in the additional dependencies in the linker property , i added the lib of my project that im trying to test.

Comment: You mentioned that you're linking a DLL library. If that's the case, then you need to [export the function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx) in order for the test to invoke it. If you don't do this, the linker won't be able to find the implementation.

Comment: If this is your first exposure to C++ exports, [the answer in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/538179/926713) might be a useful reference, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you implement test() without a return type. Which sometimes might be interpreted as default int. Add the type by changing this:

```
a::test() { return true; }
```

into this:

```
bool a::test() { return true; }
```

However it seems weird that the compiler did not complain earlier. It is still possible that the compiled file is not linked correctly.

Try changing the code first.

Comment: so how do you build your project? what ide? cmake based?

Comment: Visual studio 2008 as Dynamic Libary