# Should you: #import or "add new reference"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

In the past I would have used `#import` to gain access to functions exposed by a dynamically linked library (i.e. `*.DLL`).  Now it appears that Visual Studio has a new *Add New Reference* option.

*Project* => *Property Pages* => *Common Properties* => *References*

My question is: which approach should I use?

**REFERENCES**

The following approach was used to expose functions in our library:

- [Exporting functions from a DLL with dllexport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538134/exporting-functions-from-a-dll-with-dllexport)

**UPDATE 1**

One thing I noticed is that: unlike in C# where you can add a reference to (1) an assembly in the GAC, (2) an assembly on the file system, (3) a project within the solution. It appears that in C++ you can only *Add Reference* to a project within the current solution.

Comment: References make visual studio compile the referenced project before compiling your application, that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific rules:

- `#import` should only be used on COM type libraries.  Either the .tlb file or the .dll/.ocx if the type library is embedded in the executable file, very common.  The compiler translates the type library to a .tli and a .tlh file that contain the declarations in a format that the compiler understands as well as smart pointer types and wrapper functions that make it a lot easier to deal with memory management and runtime errors.  In C# you'd use Add Reference or Tlbimp.exe to do the same thing.
- `Add New Reference` was meant for .NET assemblies in C++/CLI projects.  The compiler imports the type declarations stored in the metadata of the assembly, the rough equivalent of a #including the .h file for a native DLL.  And the exact equivalent of Add Reference in a C# project.
- `#include` is used to include a .h file with declarations, the normal way to tell the C++ compiler about code that lives elsewhere.
- Starting in VS2012, `Add New Reference` can now also be used to generate a link instruction for a static library or DLL project that's part of the solution.  The linker simply gets the instruction to link the .lib file of the project.  No equivalent for that in C#, it does not use a linker.
- Project + Properties > Linker > Input > `Additional Dependencies` is the *other* way to do the same thing as the previous bullet.  And *must* be used if the .lib file is not generated by a project in the solution.

Note the distinction between the two sets of bullets.  The first 3 affect the compiler and are used to tell it about type declarations.  The latter 2 affect the linker and are used to tell it to link code stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've had the same dilemma. I personally prefer import. That visualizes your approach a bit better I feel. But the main reason is that that way you can just export a header file. Without it breaking because of missing lib files.

But all and all it's a pretty much a matter of personal preference I reckon.