# DLL using __stdcall without name decoration: why does it even work?

Tags: c, winapi, dll, linker

If I declare a function like this:

```
#ifdef TEST_EXPORTS
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

TESTAPI int __stdcall myadd(int a, int b);
```

The symbol in the DLL is `_myadd@8`, which makes perfect sense to me (after few hours of reading other questions here, that is).

But the windows libraries seem to do something different. They also use `__stdcall` (disguised as `WINAPI`), but the symbols in the DLLs have no name decoration. If the method above where in the windows libs, the symbol would be `myadd`.

My guess is that they use a def file to alias the symbols. But why does my linker know this when I link to one of these DLLs?

The windows header files declare these functions with `WINAPI`, so if I call them, the linker should look for the decorated name, as it is a `__stdcall` function. Yet somehow the linker knows to drop the name decoration.

I've tried to replicate this by writing a small DLL and removing the name decoration with a def file. As expected I get linker errors as the linker is still looking for the decorated name. I've done this in pure C, to make sure that c++ name mangling does not effect it.

edit: to clarify, MSVC 14.0 / VS2015, 32-bit

Comment: Note that x64 does not use name decoration.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: *"Note that x64 does not use name decoration."* - That's true for `extern "C"` only. C++ symbols must have decorated export names for overload resolution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is some barely documented magic at work here. Lets look some `WIN32` `API` function, like `RegQueryValueExW`. It is defined in the `winreg.h` file like this:

```
WINADVAPI LSTATUS APIENTRY RegQueryValueExW(...);
```

Where `WIADVAPI` is a `__declspec(dllimport)` and `APIENTRY` is a moniker for the `__stdcall` naming convention. Also note, that all functions in the header are declared as `extern "C"`. So by all means, this function should use name decoration, and its DLL export should be `_RegQueryValueExW@24`. Yet when we are looking `advapi32.dll` exports using `dumpbin /exports` command, we see an undecorated name:

[image: advapi exports]

Now lets closely examine `advapi32.lib` file using `dumpbin /headers advapi32.lib` command:

[image]

Note the `undecorate` specifier, that allows to link decorated name to the undecorated export. You could achieve the same result for your dll using a `def` file with `EXPORTS` section containing undecorated names. See [this](https://qualapps.blogspot.ru/2007/08/how-to-create-32-bit-import-libraries.html)  article and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538134/exporting-functions-from-a-dll-with-dllexport?rq=1) for the additional information.

Also, everything written above is valid only for the x86 applications. C functions in the x64 bit environment are linked [without name decoration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx):

> The form of decoration for a C function depends on the calling
>   convention used in its declaration, as shown in the following table.
>   This is also the decoration format that is used when C++ code is
>   declared to have extern "C" linkage. The default calling convention is
>   __cdecl. Note that in a 64-bit environment, functions are not decorated.

Comment: That's it. I was trying to be smart and put decorated names into the def file. The lib is indeed the missing link. It defines the decorated symbol and forwards the call to the undecorated dll symbol.