# using cpp dll in c# code

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm trying to use native c++ dll inside a c# application.

I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552348/C-fCplusinteroppluswithplusDllImport?fid=1827217&df=90&mpp=50&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed) article to get started.

Its working fine while the dll using only c files (like in the tutorial), but when using cpp files I cant make it work.

using the dumpbin tool I can see that my exported function names changed.
for example a function call 'next' changed to '?next@@YAHH@Z' and when I'm trying to call it in the c# code it cant find it.

my dll code is:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
int next(int n)
{
    return n + 1;
}
```

the c# code

```
[DllImport("lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    extern static int next(int n);
```

its the same code while using c file or cpp files

Thanks in advance
Amichai

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by cpp

Comment: @wdosanjos, thanks. i added my code to the question.

Comment: What about your C# code?

Comment: @wdosanjos, i added the c# code too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is to make a trampoline function, to externalize the use of your C++ objects.

What you are experiencing is called symbol mangling. It is a c++-specific way of naming the symbols (like the functions) in a dynamic library and an executable, to enable polymorphism.

You have to specify that you want to cancel the mangling effect by using an `extern "C"` statement in your library code, just like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int next(int n)
{
    return n + 1;
}
```

More on this [here: Exporting functions from a DLL with dllexport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538134/exporting-functions-from-a-dll-with-dllexport)

Comment: Thanks a lot. helpedme very much

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the Entry Point

An example below

```
[DllImport("lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "next", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern int next(int n);
```

Hopefully It helps.