# Using c DLL into c++ project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll, static-libraries

So I have a problem.
I have read many things but nothing seems to be working for me.

I have this C library, and I made project with file:

```
//send.h
#ifndef SEND_H
#define SEND_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
        static int Send_Sample(void);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* SEND_H */
```

And I have

```
//send.c
#include "thatLibrary.h"
static int Send_Sample(void)
{ return 0; }
```

So I created project as Empty DLL and than after that i built it, and its ok.
But when i made another project, and referenced this one in it, I do

```
#include "send.h"
```

And this include is working, he sees that .h file, but when i build the other project, it says:

```
Error   C2129   static function 'int Send_Sample(void)' declared but not defined    AzureEventHubClient c:\users\v-vlvesi\documents\github\azureeventhubclibrary\azureeventhubclient\source.cpp 9
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try removing the `static` modifier from your function.

Answer (score 1):

The 'static' keyword actually prevents the function from being exported from the DLL.  You also have to make use of **dllimport** and **dllexport**.

You can refer to this previous answer for how to instrument your code: [Exporting functions from a DLL with dllexport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538134/exporting-functions-from-a-dll-with-dllexport)