# Linker warning lnk4199

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker-warning

VS2010 Ultimate, Native C++, x64 DEBUG; under win7 64bit.

I get this linker warning in my application: 
LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:xxx.dll ignored: no imports found from xxx.dll

- I see in debugger that I successfully call functions from xxx.dll
- I give the linker appropriate xxx.lib
- I tried Properties->Linker->Input->Delay Loaded DLLs->Edit->uncheck "Inherit from parent or project defaults" - it didn't help.

What could be the solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Does xxx.lib have any symbols declared as exports? You may need to add a specific define for consumers of xxx.dll. (c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/538179/588243)