# How to add macro Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, packet-sniffers, libtins

I was trying to make a program to sniff packets and went to libtins

> If you are using a static build of libtins on Windows, then you have link your application with tins.lib. You also need to add this macro definition to your project: 
>   TINS_STATIC

What does it mean? It even does not have a value. Can some one help me how to add this in visual studio?

Does it mean something like

```
#define TINS_STATIC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841031/libtins-sniffer-undefined/61028738#61028738) answer for a full guide for using libtins with Visual Studio.

Using `#define TINS_STATIC` (before including any libtins headers) would work. Alternatively you could add `TINS_STATIC` in the project settings under `C/C++` > `Preprocessor` > `Preprocessor definitions`.

It does not need to have a value, because the libtins header only checks if the symbol is defined, not what value it has ([reference](https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins/blob/a6817528bc237970bca4d0351195151552f01db6/include/tins/macros.h#L61)):

```
// If libtins was built into a shared library
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(TINS_STATIC)
...
#endif // _WIN32 && !TINS_STATIC
```