# How to link to libtins library using CMake on Windows?

Tags: c++, cmake, libtins

I am trying to compile a project using Visual Studio Code on Windows that uses the [libtins library](https://libtins.github.io/) but I am having trouble getting CMake to link the library. I followed the main guide located on libtin's github.io page (located [here](https://libtins.github.io/download/)) and another guide from StackOverflow (located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841031/libtins-sniffer-undefined)) that uses Visual Studio, but I am using CMake so those instructions are not one-to-one for my situation. I am not familiar with CMake so my configurations are pulled from other places on StackOverflow and the CMake documentation. I have CMake downloaded and configured in Visual Studio Code by following [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux) (it translates to Windows very easily).

My CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

project(systemx_protocol)

include_directories(libtins/include npcap-sdk-1.13/Include)
link_directories(libtins/build/lib/Debug npcap-sdk-1.13/Lib/x64)

add_executable(systemx_protocol main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(systemx_protocol tins Packet Ws2_32 Iphlpapi wpcap)
```

My `main.cpp` file (from [libtins's tutorial page](https://libtins.github.io/tutorial/) with slight modifications):

```
#define TINS_STATIC

#include <iostream>
#include <tins/tins.h>

using namespace Tins;

int main() {
    EthernetII eth;
    IP *ip = new IP();
    TCP *tcp = new TCP();

    // tcp is ip's inner pdu
    ip->inner_pdu(tcp);

    // ip is eth's inner pdu
    eth.inner_pdu(ip);
    std::cout << "Hello, from systemx_protocol!\n";
}
```

I built libtins from source by cloning from the [github repository](https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins) and following the build instructions. I downloaded the Npcap SDK from [here](https://npcap.com/#download) then ran the following commands to build libtins:

```
cd <full/path/to>/libtins
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../ -DPCAP_ROOT_DIR="<full/path/to>/npcap-sdk-1.13" -DLIBTINS_ENABLE_WPA2=0 -DLIBTINS_BUILD_SHARED=0 -DLIBTINS_ENABLE_CXX11=1 -DLIBTINS_ENABLE_DOT11=0
cmake --build . --config Debug
```

The following is the full output from clicking "Build" in Visual Studio Code. It seems like CMake isn't properly linking libtins, but I'm not sure where the linking is failing.

```
[main] Building folder: <project>
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build "<full/path/to/project>/build" --config Debug --target all -j 18 --
[build] "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -S"<full/path/to/project>" -B"<full/path/to/project>\build" --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
[build] "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start "<full/path/to/project>\build\CMakeFiles" "<full/path/to/project>\build\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks"
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
[build] mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory '<full/path/to/project>/build'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/systemx_protocol.dir/depend
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory '<full/path/to/project>/build'
[build] "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" "<full/path/to/project>" "<full/path/to/project>" "<full/path/to/project>\build" "<full/path/to/project>\build" "<full/path/to/project>\build\CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir\DependInfo.cmake" --color=
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory '<full/path/to/project>/build'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/systemx_protocol.dir/build
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory '<full/path/to/project>/build'
[build] [ 50%] Linking CXX executable systemx_protocol.exe
[build] "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
[build] "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir/objects.a
[build] C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ar.exe qc CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir\objects1.rsp
[build] C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o systemx_protocol.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libsystemx_protocol.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir\linkLibs.rsp
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):<full/path/to/project>/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `Tins::EthernetII::EthernetII(Tins::HWAddress<6ull> const&, Tins::HWAddress<6ull> const&)'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `main':
[build] <full/path/to/project>/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `Tins::IPv4Address::IPv4Address(char const*)'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: <full/path/to/project>/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `Tins::IPv4Address::IPv4Address(char const*)'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: <full/path/to/project>/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `Tins::IP::IP(Tins::IPv4Address, Tins::IPv4Address)'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: <full/path/to/project>/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `Tins::TCP::TCP(unsigned short, unsigned short)'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: <full/path/to/project>/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::inner_pdu(Tins::PDU*)'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: <full/path/to/project>/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::inner_pdu(Tins::PDU*)'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `Tins::EthernetII::~EthernetII()':
[build] <full/path/to/project>/libtins/include/tins/ethernetII.h:46: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::~PDU()'
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTVN4Tins10EthernetIIE[.refptr._ZTVN4Tins10EthernetIIE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for Tins::EthernetII'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir\build.make:102: systemx_protocol.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory '<full/path/to/project>/build'
[build] mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory '<full/path/to/project>/build'
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/systemx_protocol.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:113: all] Error 2
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build "<full/path/to/project>/build" --config Debug --target all -j 18 -- exited with code: 2
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:01.190
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

My file structure looks like this (irrelevant files & directories omitted):

```
- <project>
    - main.cpp
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - libtins
        - build
            - lib
                - Debug
                    - tins.lib
        - include
            - tins
    - npcap-sdk-1.13
        - Include
        - Lib
            - x64
                - Packet.lib
                - wpcap.lib
    - build
```

What is causing the linking to fail? Am I using the wrong options for the CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: ``CMakeFiles\systemx_protocol.dir\linkLibs.rsp`` contains the following:   
``-L<full/path/to/project>/libtins/build/lib/Debug  -L"<full/path/to/project>/NPCAP-~1.13/Lib/x64"  -ltins -lPacket -lWs2_32 -lIphlpapi -lwpcap -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32``

Comment: Looks like you have built libtins for **Visual Studio** (`cmake --build . --config Debug` implies using *multi-configuration* CMake generator), but your project is building with **MinGW**. Visual Studio and MinGW binaries are not compatible. For build libtins for MinGW specify additional parameter `-G"MinGW Makefiles"` when configure the project (`cmake ../ -DPCAP_ROOT_DIR=...`).