# Problem passing parameters from Excel VBA x64 to C++ dll x64

Tags: c++, excel, dll

.h file conent:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double WINAPI P452Calc(int, int *);
```

.cpp file content:

```
double WINAPI P452Calc(int i, int * ii) {
    return i;
}
```

VBA code:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function P452Calc Lib "P452Lib.dll" (ByVal i As Integer, ByRef ii As Integer) As Double
Public Function Test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ii As Integer
    i = 33
    ii = 2
    Test = P452Calc(i, ii)
End Function
```

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9833F917F (kernel32.dll) in EXCEL.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000021. (21h == 33 i variable value)

I can not figure out what exactly wrong.

Comment: The default calling convention for C++ is `__cdecl`.  Did you specify that in your VB code?  Or similarly, did you specify `__stdcall` in the C++ code, to match the default VB calling convention?

Comment: Yes, the WINAPI macro resolved to ___stdcall. I am also used __stdcall directrly in C++ code, but got the same problem, so I've reverted to this code and still stuck.

Comment: `Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000021` -- Well, the call believes that the first parameter is a pointer.  This still looks like an issue with the incorrect calling convention being used.

Comment: I've installed x86 excel and make x86 dll, finally it works, with all params byref, will try to flip back to 64 later.

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue, though whatever is first in the parameter list is passed along just fine.  I don't have the option of switching to 32-bit.  I agree that it looks like calling convention, but I'm using __stdcall too.  The irony is I've got  a preceding function with 7 parameters that works peachy!

Answer (score 0):

> .h file conent:
>
> ```
> extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double WINAPI P452Calc(int, int *);
> ```
>
> VBA code:
>
> ```
> Declare PtrSafe Function P452Calc Lib "P452Lib.dll" (ByVal i As Integer, ByRef ii As Integer) As Double
> ```

VBA's [`Integer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/integer-data-type) is a 16-bit integral type, while MS C implementation uses [32-bit `int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp?view=msvc-170#sizes-of-built-in-types). You need to use [`Long`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/long-data-type) in VBA to match the `int` in .h; or alternatively, you need to use `short` in C to match Basic's `Integer`.